# (Python, Windows) Calling class functions from other classes

Tags: python, windows, class, function, variables

I'm trying to call a function in one class from another class. Here is my code:

```
import os

class GameRoom():

    msgLine1 = ""
    msgLine2 = ""
    msgLine3 = ""
    msgLine4 = ""
    msgLine5 = ""

    def GameStatus(self):
        while True:
            os.system('cls')
            print self.msgLine1
            print self.msgLine2
            print self.msgLine3
            print self.msgLine4
            print self.msgLine5 + "\n"
            print "Do what?\n"
            userDecision = raw_input()
            if userDecision.upper() == "GO":
                Player().Go()
                break
            else:
                self.CycleMessages("That's not a valid choice!")

    def CycleMessages(self,newMsg="error"):
        self.msgLine5 = self.msgLine4
        self.msgLine4 = self.msgLine3
        self.msgLine3 = self.msgLine2
        self.msgLine2 = self.msgLine1
        self.msgLine1 = newMsg

class Player():
    def Go(self):
        GameRoom().CycleMessages("Player goes.")
        GameRoom().GameStatus()

def main():
    GameRoom().GameStatus()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I call `CycleMessages` through itself, the lines fill up with 'That's not a valid choice!' normally, like they should. When I call `CycleMessages` from the `Player` class, all of the lines clear instead of displaying 'Player goes.'. 'error' doesn't display either.

I would like 'Player goes.' to show up when I call `Player().Go()`. How do I do this? I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because when you call `GameRoom().CycleMessages("Player goes.")`, you're calling it on a new instance of `GameRoom`. Easy fix:

```
class GameRoom():

    def GameStatus(self):
        ...
            if userDecision.upper() == "GO":
                # Pass `Player` this instance of `GameRoom`
                Player().Go(self)
                break
            else:
                self.CycleMessages("That's not a valid choice!")

class Player():

    def Go(self, game):
        # And here, call `CycleMessages` on the passed instance of `GameRoom`.
        game.CycleMessages("Player goes.")
        game.GameStatus()
```

Also, this wasn't your question, but you might want to consider changing your naming conventions (see: [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions)).

Comment: I'd rename the `GameRoom` argument to avoid shadowing the class name. Also, to avoid ever-deepening recursion, I'd suggest dropping the `GameStatus()` call from the end of `Player.Go` in favor of just returning. Then just remove the `break` line from `GameStatus` and you'll have just a single loop.

Comment: Thank you! It works fine now. I knew about the naming conventions, but I was being a lazy person or something like that. Sorry for taking so long to respond!

Answer (score 1):

Part of the issue you're facing (and perhaps the reason it's confusing to you) is that you're trying to use class variables to hold your messages, but in fact you're not modifying them. Whenever you type `self.variable = something` you're going to be assigning to an instance variable, even if a class variable exists with the same name. That's because while you can access class variables via `self`, you can't assign to them that way.

You can avoid this by naming the class variable more precisely as `GameRoom.variable`, but instead I suggest avoiding class variables completely. They're rarely useful for anything other than constants. Here's how you could set up the same thing you have now with instance variables:

```
class GameRoom(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.message1 = ""
        self.message2 = ""
        # etc...
```

The rest of the code can be the same (it's already manipulating instance variables).

Once you are set on using instance variables, the trouble you'll run into is that you're creating a new instance of your classes whenever you want to access their methods. That is, your `GameRoom` creates a new `Player` instance over and over, and the `Player` class creates new `GameRoom` instances after each move. This is generally not what you want to do. Instead, you probably want to create just one instance of each of them, and keep reusing them.

@kuyan's answer shows how you can avoid creating a new `GameRoom` instance in your `Player.Go` method, but you probably want to avoid creating lots of `Player` instances too (especially if you're going to have anything complicated in the `Player` class later on).

I'd do:

```
def GameStatus(self):
    player = Player()    # create a Player instance in a local variable

    # ...

    if userDecision.upper() == "GO":
        player.Go(self)  # use the variable!
```

Another option would be to add the player creation to the `__init__` method (assign it to `self.player` or some other name on the instance). Then you can access the same `Player` instance from any number of methods within `GameRoom`. Or you could even make it a parameter to the `__init__` method, if you want the same `Player` instance to be useable in different rooms.